# Disable Script Prompt on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion

I was wondering...

Is it possible to disable the prompt on Mac OSX Lion that says.

> Are you sure you want to run this script? [Yes, Cancel]

I added this script to the "Login Items" File to start automatically when I login, but the prompt still pops up. Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What script are you talking about?

Comment: @drootang I created it. It welcomes me in a robot voice and then opens a list of applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an Applescript is saved as an application so that it can be run independently of Script Editor with a double-click, there is an option to have a "startup screen" which, in Snow Leopard and before (I don't have Lion), offers a choice between "Run" (the default) or "Quit". I imagine you might have enabled that feature without realizing, or maybe in Lion it is now activated by default.